# Serialization in same JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, serialization, session-cookies

Is serialization necessary while writing and reading an object in the same JVM?

> Session objects must implement serializable in order to maintain it after restart of server.

As same JVM is used why session objects must implement serializable?

Comment: Serialization is used when you have to send and receive the object across the network. It is independent of the JVM implementation.

Comment: @ZahidKhan (Java) serialization is turning Java objects into bytes. Whether you send those bytes over the network is a separate thing. You might as well save them to a file or database (as is done to sessions), or do anything else you would do to bytes (including sending over the network).

Comment: Yes, @Kayaman that's the correct definition. What I tried to convey is - that it is independent of JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is required because the session objects may be stored in a file, a database or may be transported to another service node via network. Even the included objects must implement `Serializable`.

Why these requirements were set? Because a session must last longer than a request. Nobody can guarantee that the same JVM will still exist when the next request comes with the same Session ID - so there should be a redundancy or failover solution that ensures that the session will survive. There are many solutions for this, but the actual solution doesn't even matter - but Serialization ensures that it will work.